# HoloLens/Unity - Missing Debug framework Error DEP8000

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, hololens

I'm running Unity 2018.1.7f1 on Windows 10 Insider Preview 10.0.17711, and suddenly I can't deploy a debug version of my app to HoloLens. It seems to be an issue either with the latest OS preview, or the new version of Unity.

> Error DEP8000 : Unexpected deployment failure : RemoteCommandException
>   : Windows cannot install package Template3D_1.0.0.0_x86__pzq3xp76mxafg
>   because this package depends on a framework that could not be found.
>   Provide the framework "Microsoft.VCLibs.140.00.Debug" published by
>   "CN=Microsoft Corporation, O=Microsoft Corporation, L=Redmond,
>   S=Washington, C=US", with neutral or x86 processor architecture and
>   minimum version 14.0.26428.1, along with this package to install. The
>   frameworks with name "Microsoft.VCLibs.140.00.Debug" currently
>   installed are:
>   {Microsoft.VCLibs.140.00.Debug_14.0.26128.0_x86__8wekyb3d8bbwe}

I have the latest VS2017 installed  all the Windows SDKs installed up to the current    10.0.17134.0, and the latest HoloLens emulator/VS2017 templates. I've tried adding the missing framework using PowerShell (Add-AppxPackage). Stumped.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is here:

https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=30135 - Microsoft .NET Framework Repair Tool. It immediately found and fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I had same issue. Then I remembered that even in Microsoft's tutorial `release` version is used instead of `debug`.

I'm referring to following text:

> Using the top toolbar in Visual Studio, change the target from Debug to Release and from ARM to X86.

You can find same instruction in both tutorials:

- [MR Basics 101](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/holograms-101)
- [MR Basics 101E](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/holograms-101e)

Now I realize that this doesn't solves your issue directly because you will be deploying release version and not debug one but I guess that there might be others stumbling upon this issue so this way you can at least continue developing, and if Microsoft doesn't use debug version than just maybe it isn't meant to be used.