# Wrong Microsoft.VCLibs version inclued in hololens build

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, hololens

I am using Unity to build a simple hololens app.

I am just using the build window from [MixedRealityToolkit](https://github.com/Microsoft/MixedRealityToolkit-Unity/blob/master/GettingStarted.md)

I have been doing this many times, without problems. However after a bunch of updated the installation of the app fails

Now I have updated Hololens to the newest version 17134.165.x86fre.rs4 (April 10 2018 release).
At the same time i have updated Unity, Visual Studio 2017 and Windows 10 SDK. The windows 10 SDK is 10.0.171340.0

Everything builds fine, and the App package is created without any errors.

**The Problem**

When i try to install the app on my hololens i get the following error

```
Windows cannot install package [x] because this package depends on a framework that could not be found. Provide the framework "Microsoft.VCLibs.140.00.Debug" published by "CN=Microsoft Corporation, O=Microsoft Corporation, L=Redmond, S=Washington, C=US", with neutral or x86 processor architecture and minimum version 14.0.26428.1, along with this package to install. The frameworks with name "Microsoft.VCLibs.140.00.Debug" currently installed are: {Microsoft.VCLibs.140.00.Debug_14.0.25830.2_x86__8wekyb3d8bbwe}(Package failed updates, dependency or conflict validation.)
```

The problem seems to be that a wrong Microsoft.VCLibs.140.00.Debug dependency is used. It needs `14.0.26428.1` but is using `14.0.25830.2`.

**What i have found so far**

I can see that the dependency VCLIBS file included as package dependency seems to be an older file (something installed with a previous SDK or Visual Studio version) However i can not figure out where to find a newer version.

I have tried with both Unity 2018 and 2017, but Unity does not seem to be the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i figured out how to solve this.

It seems like the problem was that i had to run the app from within visual studio.
When i did that, suddenly it realised that the dependencies where out of date, and automatically managed to update them.

So instead of building from `Mixed Reality Toolkit -> Build Window` i should create the solution with `File -> Buld Settings -> Build`. Then i should open the solution in visual studio. Set the platform to x86, Choose to run on device, and finaly hit play.

Answer (score 1):

Quickfix: Changing your build configuration from `debug` to `release` should enable you to install app on hololens.

I have provided more details here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51555857/6357154, but I don't have enough reputation to post this as a comment.

Comment: Thank you but this did not work, then it just got another problem with the version of .net core.

Answer (score 0):

Try downloading the given below setup to install the dependency.

=>C++ Runtime v12 framework package for Desktop Bridge (Project Centennial)
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=53176

Then you can manualy locate the dependency at given below folder
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Kits\10\ExtensionSDKs

[image]